# GCM doesn't work on samsung tablets

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, samsung-mobile

I verified that the app can receive notifications on galaxy nexus tablet (4.2)and samsung galaxy s3 phone(4.1.1), but cannot work on samsung galaxy tab 10.1 (4.0.4) and samsung 7 inch tablet(4.0.4)

There is more than one google account signed in to the tablet. **I received the registration ID, and while I send the notifications I get the error**

Error log,

```
05-22 14:40:47.220: W/GTalkService(10357): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast
 intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
 act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[ xxx ] (has extras) }
 05-22 14:40:47.225: W/GTalkService(10357): Receiver package not found,
 unregister application com.myapp.example sender
```

Android manifest has all the necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
    <permission android:name="com.myapp.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.example.gcm.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                 <category android:name="com.myapp.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".gcm.GCMService" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started working after I modified the category in the receiver,

```
from
 <category android:name="com.myapp.example.gcm" />

to
 <category android:name="com.myapp.example" />
```

Comment: Life saver ;) strange thing is that using com.myapp.example.gcm works on a bunch of other devices..