# android google cloud messaging protocol not found while trying to register device

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have been following the google cloud messaging tutorial on http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html I followed this guide step by step and managed to write application that succesfully registers with google cloud messager on emulator (4.4.2, API 19). It registered just fine and returned registration ID.

The problem is, when I uploaded the programm on samsung galaxy tab (4.1.2) the programm returned IOexception "Protocol not found" during registerinBackground method. I tried this on another tab that had Android 4.1.3(if i remember correctly), but i had the same problem. Now I have no clue what to do next. Could anyone pount me in the right direction?

log states that:

```
    08-21 22:48:57.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-21 22:48:57.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4590): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable    to instantiate receiver com.led.connection.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.led.connection.GcmBroadcastReceiver
    08-21 22:48:57.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2261)
```

**Solved** Problem with the protocol not found was because of my send registration ID to backend implementation. Thank you for your help with GcmBroadcastRecever Hungry Coder

Comment: This one had a strange fix. I don't know if it still works. You can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702172/gcm-doesnt-work-on-samsung-tablets

Comment: This did not work. I allready had package name without gcm extension

Comment: Did you try it on any phone to see whether this problem happens only on tab or not?

Comment: I did not, don't have an android phone available at the moment

Comment: Just make sure that your apk are bundled with play services lib. First, check if it is added in the Android app project dependency (Go to project properties > java build path > libraries > android dependencies and be sure that google_play_services_lib jar is added). Then go to the next tab (order and export), be sure that "Android Dependencies" is checked in the list.

Comment: Both google_play_services_lib jar is added and Android Dependencies is checked in the list. could it be something to do with GcmBroadcastReceiver class? But then again, why did the programm work on emulator

Comment: That's strange! ClassNotFoundException is thrown when your libraries are not properly bundled with the app. I think, there might be something wrong in those tablets' play service versions. Did you check for the playServices as suggested in the google doc? (By using GooglePlayServicesUtil)

Comment: And, also double check whether you followed these steps when you included the library: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: Yes i did it as shown in the link i provided in my question. There is checkPlayServices method that uses GooglePlayServicesUtil

Comment: I also did follow steps in http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: Ok, i added google api to my build path and my problem with BroadCastreceiver does not crash does not exist anymore, but i still have the problem with registration, where method registerInBackground returns Protocol not gound